# Can't able to merge branch to main branch in github

Tags: git, github, repository, github-for-windows

I developed a github repository with empty main in GitHub.
Then i created local repo in git and done basic operations to push...

```
git init
```

for new empty repo

```
git add .
```

for adding all files in local repo

```
git commit -m "first update"
git add remote origin <github repo link>.git
```

I've tried merge and rebase too....

```
git merge origin/main
git rebase origin/main
```

still it was unable to merge it
please help with a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge or rebase initially, just push with `-u` flag which set upstream to `origin/main`

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin $(repolink).git
git push -u origin main
```

Next push use `git push origin main`